# calling methods in Spring configurations

Tags: java, spring

I am tying to migrate hard coded database dependencies into the spring framework

so

```
Mongo m = new Mongo("192.168.0.0.1");

DB db = m.getDB("db name");

db.authenticate("user", "pass".toCharArray());
```

would become:

```
<mongo:mongo host="192.168.0.0.1" port="27017" />

<bean id="mongoDatabase"
  factory-bean="mongo"
  factory-method="getDB">
  <constructor-arg value="db name" />
</bean>
```

But I am not sure how to call authenticate.  It would be nice to know the best way to do this generally.

(Usernames and passwords have been changed to protect the innocent)

Comment: You don't say which version of spring you are using. If 3.x and later you should consider using the java config support for this. failing that write your own factory bean that does all the set up for you. See  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java and http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use <[mongo:db-factory](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-db-factory-xml)>.

Comment: this looks like the best practice way to do it.